# Ruby-like yield in Python 3

Tags: ruby, python-3.x

All,

I really love the way Ruby does yield.

```
def wrap_print
  puts 'A'
  yield
  puts 'C'
end

wrap_print do
  puts 'B'
end

> A
> B
> C
```

I haven't found a way to emulate this in Python. Does anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I immediately figured this out. Preserving my result as a complete example.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def wrap_print():
  print('A')
  yield
  print('C')

with wrap_print():
  print('B')
```

If you want to pass a value to the block.

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def wrap_print():
    print('A')
    yield 'B'
    print('C')

with wrap_print() as foo:
    print(foo)
```

Answer (score 3):

`yield` simply transfers control to the block. In other words, it calls the block.

In Python, functions are first-class, so there is no need to distinguish between different types of callable objects like Ruby does (method, blocks, and procs). So, the Python equivalent of yielding to a block is simply a function call:

```
def wrap_print(f):
  print('A')
  f()
  print('C')

def _():
  print('B')

wrap_print(_)
```

The fact that you need to define a named function is because of a limitation in Python's anonymous function literals that can contain only one single expression.

For example, in this case, you don't need a named function:

```
def transform(list, transformer):
  newlist = []
  for el in list:
    newlist.append(transformer(el))
  return newlist

transform([1, 2, 3], lambda el: el * 2)
#>>> [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: While this is functionally equivalent, it does not maintain the same syntactic similarities as my answer. In particular, you must define a named method if that method is more than one line. Thanks.